# Activate text box if the "Other" option is selected and POST data

Tags: javascript, html

I found this code on another entry on here which works fine except the text field overwrites with nothing if a colour is selected form the select box so nothing is sent in the POST. Can anyone help?

```
<html> 
<head>  
<script type="text/javascript">
function CheckColors(val){
 var element=document.getElementById('color');
 if(val=='pick a color'||val=='others')
   element.style.display='block';
 else  
   element.style.display='none';
}

</script> 
</head>
<body>
  <select name="color" onchange='CheckColors(this.value);'> 
    <option>pick a color</option>  
    <option value="red">RED</option>
    <option value="blue">BLUE</option>
    <option value="others">others</option>
  </select>
<input type="text" name="color" id="color" style='display:none;'/>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks,

John

Comment: Is there ony certain colors you want them to be able to select? If not how about `<input type='color' onchange='checkColors(this.value)'>`, If you want the color name then there are js libraries to change the hex to name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need to set the selected color to the text box
in the Javascript section, change this:

```
    if(val=='pick a color'||val=='others'){ //Always use curly brackets 
         element.style.display='';
         element.value = '';
    }
    else { 
         element.style.display='none';
         element.value = val;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @YuriG, that works to a point but if others is selected the text vox is pre-populated with others and I would like this to be blank. Is that possible?

Comment: in that case you can add 
`element.value = ''` in the "if" part of the condition

Comment: I gave that a go @YuriG but it then does not display the text box if others is selected.

Comment: Just to be on the same page: when you select "others", do you want the textbox to be empty or do you want it to be populated with some value?

Comment: @YuriGI would like the textbox to be empty please? So the user can type in any other colour that's not in the select. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @JohnHiggins, please find the fix in the answer

Comment: @YuriGI - Sorry, it was a typo my end. All working fine, thanks for your help.